# Strip dots from IP addresses in Mysql

Tags: mysql, replace

I need to strip dots from a columns of IP addresses in MySQL table 'visits', I used the following query, what's wrong with it?

```
UPDATE 'visits' SET 'IP' = REPLACE('IP', '.', '');
```

Thanks

Comment: Use backticks ` instead of single quotes `'` for table and column name

Comment: Removing dots removes uniqueness, if this is to get a numeric representation then consider `INET_ATON()`

Comment: You might want to show the layout of your "visits" table and any errors you are getting to clarify your question.

Comment: INET_ATON works! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use backticks `` ` `` instead of single quotes `'` for table and column name

```
UPDATE `visits` SET `IP` = REPLACE(`IP`, '.', '');
```

That said, this method may create issues.

For e.g. you have two IPs: `10.1.1.11` and `10.1.11.1`

After your update, both will become - `101111` and there is no way to tell which is which.

As @Alex said in the comments, if you want to represent the IP as numeric value, consider `INET_ATON()` instead, which returns an integer that represents the numeric value of the address in network byte order (big endian).

```
UPDATE `visits` SET `IP` = INET_ATON(`IP`);
```

It'll return unique number for an IP.

```
10.1.1.11 - 167837963
10.1.11.1 - 167840513
```